# Monitoring the execution of all process

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, process, monitoring, monitor

How I can do it?

I don't want to use a timer + an array of processes (because that's the newbie way that I allways did) I'm looking for something better and improved.

I've tried using ManagementEventWatcher but this code example is not working in Windows 7 (I don't get any error, but is not showing the MsgBoxes):

```
Public Class Form1

Dim WithEvents startWatch As New System.Management.ManagementEventWatcher(New System.Management.WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace"))
Dim WithEvents stopWatch As New System.Management.ManagementEventWatcher(New System.Management.WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace"))

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AddHandler startWatch.EventArrived, AddressOf startWatch_EventArrived
    AddHandler stopWatch.EventArrived, AddressOf stopWatch_EventArrived
    startWatch.Start()
    stopWatch.Start()
End Sub

Public Sub startWatch_EventArrived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Management.EventArrivedEventArgs)
    MsgBox("Process started: " & e.NewEvent.Properties("ProcessName").Value)
End Sub

Private Sub stopWatch_EventArrived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Management.EventArrivedEventArgs)
    MsgBox("Process stopped: " & e.NewEvent.Properties("ProcessName").Value)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Closing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Closing
    startWatch.Stop()
    stopWatch.Stop()
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Management Event Watcher can do what exactly you are looking.
Have a look:
[ManagementEventWatcher.Stop Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementeventwatcher.stop%28v=vs.100%29.ASPx)

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers, to get more understanding how to **not** answer. Namely: "Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question": **barely more than a link to an external site**

Answer (score 1):

This will get the name and PID of each running process, simply modify this code to get any additional information...

```
 Dim processList As String
 For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcesses()
    processList = processList & " " & p.SessionId & vbNewLine
 Next()
 MsgBox(processList)
```

Comment: Thankyou but I know that method and it's only for what you are saying, your example gets all the running process, then to monitoring the execution of all new opened processes first I need to get the an array of processes like in your example, then elapsed "X" ms of time I need to get another array of processes and compare it with the old array to search for a new entry. I know how to do it like that but really I want to evade that method that's why I'm asking how to do it using something more and simplified as ManagementEventWatcher, but really thankyou for your answer

Comment: Just use a timer, then call the sub with the Tick event to compare the two lists...

Comment: @ Sam I know but like I say I preffer to use another way, thanks